# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> when I try to test my app using localhost

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm getting an error when I try to test my app on localhost:3000 in the Router, how can I fix it? I'm newbie in React & React Router also, what kind of problems can cause this.

App.js:

```
import { NavBar } from "./shared/NavBar"
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { BooksList } from "./BooksList";
import { CreateBook } from "./CreateBook";
import { UpdateBook } from "./UpdateBook";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <NavBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/create-book">
                    <CreateBook />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/update-book">
                    <UpdateBook />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                    <BooksList />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

NavBar component:

```
import { Flex, Image, Box, Link as StyledLink } from "rebass/styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const NavBar = () => {
    return (
        <Flex bg="black" color="white" justifyContent="center">
                <Flex px={2} width="100%" alignItems="center">
                    <Link component={StyledLink} variant="nav" to="/">
                        React CRUD App
                    </Link>
                    <Box mx="auto" />
                        <Link component={StyledLink} variant="nav" to="/create-book">
                            Add new item
                        </Link>
                </Flex>
        </Flex>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you use `<Link>` ouside of a `<Router>` in your other components?

Comment: Is `App` wrapped in a `Router` component? Can you include all relevant component code, specifically where you are rendering any `Link` and/or `Router` components?

Comment: @DrewReese yeah, added

Comment: And what of any routing context, i.e. `Router`? Are you rendering your app into a `router` component?

Comment: @DrewReese for now it's returning null (update/create) - just for test, I try only start my local server and it gives me such errors

Comment: You need to provide a routing context for the `Link`, `Route`, and `Redirect` components by rendering them into a ReactTree with a `Router` above them. Even for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your routing to **`BrowserRouter`**

import

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

and wrap routes

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
           <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/create-book">
                    <CreateBook />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/update-book">
                    <UpdateBook />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                    <BooksList />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
           </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: `NavBar` suspiciously sounds like a component that would have links in it. Surely that should be included to be within a routing context, no?

Comment: @DrewReese missed, that should be inside, Thanks!